# Command-Line linux OpenGL processing

Tags: linux, opengl, command-line, 3d

I need to build a command line tool, that will take a 3D model as an argument, and will output photos of it, that may or may not be processed by this application. The tool will be deployed on Linux, but I want to make it as cross-platform as possible.

The program is not supposed to present a window of any kind, or accept any other input apart from the command line arguments.

I was wondering, how would someone approach this? I am currently able to display the 3D model on-screen with the help of GLFW, which actually drives my event handlers to peripheral input, and also my main loop. However, I don't know if using GLFW will help me if I want to make a command-line program with input-output as files.

Does anyone have any indications as to how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

1. create invisible/hidden window,
2. use its gl context to render to FBO and
3. use readpixels to save that to file

Comment: There will be no windows in the server. The windowing system will not be installed. Is the window system necessary to install in order to produce an OpenGL output?

Comment: @csotiriou you need an openGL context to do anything with openGL, there may be solutions to create a context without a windowing system but it's much simpler to do this with one

Comment: @csotiriou: Plus, on Windows (non-server!) you don't have the option of not having a window system anyway. So the special case is actually Linux without an X session - not the other way round.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Well, the problem with X is, that OpenGL rendering works only if the X server is actually active on the console. If it's just running, but the vt it's on is not active, OpenGL will not work. Mesa actually offers offscreen OpenGL support without an X server running (off-screen mesa).

Comment: Rendering to hidden/invisible window will not work. The Xorg standard says that if a window is hidden or not visible, it's content is undefined. I hope you meant rendering to off-screen buffer.

Comment: @BЈовић that's what I meant with FBO

Comment: still, nothing is going to be rendered to a hidden window. What you read with with glReadPixels is going to be garbage, or all black.

Answer (score 2):

For OpenGL to work you need an OpenGL context. Which used to require some kind of windowing system active, that could produce you some drawable for which the context could be created.

Some OpenGL implementations, like Mesa, actually allow you to create an OpenGL context for drawables that are created without a windowing system; Mesa calls this "off-screen mesa". With Gallium3D drivers on Linux this even may give you GPU acceleration. But usually you end up in the "softpipe" software rasterizer.

> Does anyone have any indications as to how to approach this?

Don't use OpenGL for it. OpenGL is mostly meant for creating interactive graphics; but of course if your goal is visualization of complex data, then a GPU would be better suited.

With NVidia hardware you'll need to use an X server for that; the X server must be running and active on the console for this to work. AMD hardware with the open source drivers and Mesa may give you off-screen capabilities without X (but I never tried that).

On Windows Server you don't have proper OpenGL support anyway (just v1.4 and very slow), so don't bother with it.

Comment: Thanks. Can we have a Linux server with X active on the console but with no active any kind of GUI? I wonder if we can just install the libraries and start the X system, but without actually having a GUI. And yes, we suppose that the server is strong enough, and has the necessary hardware loaded. Most importantly: You say "Don't use OpenGL for it". Do you have any alternatives for taking photos a 3D model from various aspects?

Comment: @csotiriou: Yes it's perfectly possible to run an X server without a desktop environment or a window manager. On a typical Linux installation you can use the command `startx $YOUR_CLIENT_BINARY -- $DISPLAY_NUMBER`. Or you're using good old `xinit` with the respective user's `~/.xinitrc` execing the client. Be aware though, that once the last client closes it's connection the X server will reset, which may include termination. So you'll normally to have some client permanently running. A simple no-frills window manager would do the trick.

Comment: @csotiriou: An OpenGL program that's used for rendering pictures that are read back should use a FBO in any case to avoid problems with pixel ownership tests (otherwise the window must be at least at large as your target image and be visible at a whole). If you want multiple users being able to use the X server you can call `xhost +localhost` from the `.xinitrc` script (given that you use that), so that any user on the local machine can connect to the X server.

Comment: @csotiriou:  Alternatively make the `~/.Xauthority` file created for the user starting the X server readable for anyone and set its absolute path into the environment variable `XAUTHORITY`. Also remember to set the environment variable `DISPLAY` for all programs requiring the X server to the right value. As window manager I suggest something simple, like `ratpoison` which is absolutely bare bones. Or you don't use a WM at all, but then you need *some* client to keep the server open. In the most simple case this might be a helper program that just does that.